# NerdDinner turorial: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am following step by step the ASP.NET NerdDinner tutorial and I get to this step http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/nerddinner/build-a-model-with-business-rule-validations.
I did everything exactly as on tutorial (excepting the project name) and I'm getting the following errors:

```
The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'AdventureTrip.Models.Trip.GetRuleViolations()' and 'AdventureTrip.Models.Trip.GetRuleViolations()'
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Trip.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Data.Linq;

namespace AdventureTrip.Models
{
    public partial class Trip
    {
        public bool IsValid
        {
            get { return (GetRuleViolations().Count() == 0); }
        }

        public IEnumerable<RuleViolation> GetRuleViolations()
        {
            yield break;
        }

        partial void OnValidate(ChangeAction action)
        {
            if (!IsValid)
                throw new ApplicationException("Rule violation prevent saving");
        }
    }

    public partial class Trip
    {
        public IEnumerable<RuleViolation> GetRuleViolations()
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Title))
                yield return new RuleViolation("Title required", "Title");

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Description))
                yield return new RuleViolation("Description required", "Description");

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(OrganisedBy))
                yield return new RuleViolation("HostedBy required", "HostedBy");

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Address))
                yield return new RuleViolation("Address required", "Address");

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Country))
                yield return new RuleViolation("Country required", "Country");

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(ContactPhone))
                yield return new RuleViolation("Phone# required", "ContactPhone");

            if (!PhoneValidator.IsValidNumber(ContactPhone, Country))
                yield return new RuleViolation("Phone# does not match country", "ContactPhone");
            yield break;
        }
        public class PhoneValidator
        {
            static IDictionary<string, Regex> countryRegex = new Dictionary<string, Regex>() 
            {
                { "USA", new Regex("^[2-9]\\d{2}-\\d{3}-\\d{4}$")},
                { "UK", new Regex("(^1300\\d{6}$)|(^1800|1900|1902\\d{6}$)|(^0[2|3|7|8]{1}[0-9]{8}$)|(^13\\d{4}$)|(^04\\d{2,3}\\d{6}$)")},
                { "Netherlands", new Regex("(^\\+[0-9]{2}|^\\+[0-9]{2}\\(0\\)|^\\(\\+[0-9]{2}\\)\\(0\\)|^00[0-9]{2}|^0)([0-9]{9}$|[0-9\\-\\s]{10}$)")},
            };
            public static bool IsValidNumber(string phoneNumber, string country)
            {
                if (country != null && countryRegex.ContainsKey(country))
                    return countryRegex[country].IsMatch(phoneNumber);
                else
                    return false;
            }
            public static IEnumerable<string> Countries
            {
                get { return countryRegex.Keys; }
            }
        }
    }

    public class RuleViolation
    {
        public string ErrorMessage { get; private set; }
        public string PropertyName { get; private set; }

        public RuleViolation(string errorMessage)
        {
            ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
        }

        public RuleViolation(string errorMessage, string propertyName)
        {
            ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
            PropertyName = propertyName;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Method `GetRuleViolations` is supposed to be a part of the `Trip` class, not the `RuleViolation` class, where it indeed does not make any sense.

Comment: Show your `Trip` class. Its needs properties for `Title`, `Description` etc.

Comment: @Andrei I've made the change, but now I get the following error on the first 'if' : A get or set accessor expected

Comment: @PavelValeriu, so now follow Stephen's question and make sure Trip class indeed contains properties Title, Description, etc

Comment: Checked in database and it contains those properties

Comment: @PavelValeriu, not the database, the class definition. C# code, in other words, presumably generated as the DB context

Comment: I'm not sure how am I suposed to do this...the code from description is from Trip.cs.

Comment: @PavelValeriu, You need a class for `Trip` i.e. `public class Trip` containing the properties your referring to (in addition to the partial class)

Comment: @StephenMuecke the properties are the following? public string Title { get; set;}     public string Address { get; set; } etc. ??

Comment: Yes (should be 7 of them - matching each of the `String.IsNullOrEmpty(xxxx)` properties)

Comment: Now it returns me an error on the new `Trip` class: `Missing partial modifier on declaration of type 'AdventureTrip.Models.Trip'; another partial declaration of this type exists`

Comment: @StephenMuecke perhaps I have to add the properties inside of the `public partial class Trip` ?

Comment: Just make both of them `public partial class Trip`

Comment: Done, but the first `if` still has this error ... `A get or set accessor expected`

Comment: Do you have properties? - `public string Title { get; set; }` etc

Comment: Yes, the properties are added

Comment: And you have moved `public IEnumerable<RuleViolation> GetRuleViolations()` {..}` from `class RuleViolation` into the `class Trip` as Andrei noted?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I've updated the code from description. I solved error `A get or set accessor expected` but now another error pops up...`The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'AdventureTrip.Models.Trip.GetRuleViolations()' and 'AdventureTrip.Models.Trip.GetRuleViolations()'`

Comment: You can only have one `public IEnumerable<RuleViolation> GetRuleViolations()` method - the one you have with just `yield break;` needs to be deleted

Comment: This solves the problem, thank you very much for helping me!